# Unable to sort the field with type: EmbeddedReference in the cms-config.yaml file for SKYGEAR-CMS

Tags: yaml, skygear

I am managing a project that is built using **SkyGear CMS**. As per the Documentation I have the flexibility to change the *cms-config.yaml* only. Now I need to sort a field with *type: EmbeddedReference* as shown in the code below.

```
show:
  label: Offers
  fields:
    - name: packages
      type: EmbeddedReference
      default_sort:
        name: night_count
        ascending: false
      label: Packages
      reference_via_back_reference: package
      reference_from_field: offer_id

      reference_fields:
        - name: night_count
          type: Integer
        - type: _created_at
        - type: _updated_at
      reference_delete_action: delete-record
```

I tried using the default_sort(as per the give documentation of [SkyGear](https://docs.skygear.io/guides/cms/cms-field-type/)) but it has no effect if tried with any field. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`default_sort` is an attribute for record list. In your case, `reference_position_field` and `reference_position_ascending` should be the attributes you are looking for.

BTW, `EmbeddedReference` is not a valid field type in the latest version but `embedded_reference_list`.

The configuration would look like this:

```
show:
  label: Offers
  fields:
    - name: packages
      type: embedded_reference_list
      label: Packages
      reference_via_back_reference: package
      reference_from_field: offer_id
      reference_position_field: night_count
      reference_position_ascending: false

      reference_fields:
        - name: night_count
          type: Integer
        - type: _created_at
        - type: _updated_at
      reference_delete_action: delete-record
```

Comment: That works men, thanks for the help. I was wondering if you have a reference Document for the same so that I can get more info on the supported keywords. That will be really helpful.